Help identify a skit - SNL / MadTV?
Trying to identify this skit.  I think this was from an SNL or MadTV episode but I'm stumped.
The premise was a few co-workers.  One was a bumbling idiot and one was the smart one.  The issue was that the rest of the workers believed the bumbling idiot rather than the smart worker.
This infuriated the smart coworker, who eventually had a melt down and snapped because he couldn't understand how people were listening to the incompetent  coworker.
For the life of me, I can't remember what this skit was... Any ideas?  Please help settle my brain.

Do you remember what they looked like? The approximate year? Any of the dialogue?

From the description, it sounds like something Mad TV would do.

Also sounds like Frank Grimes (or "Grimey", as he liked to be called) from an episode of The Simpsons. But I imagine you'd remember if the people were animated.

Thanks guys..  I think it was the Grimey episode.  It definitely was 10+ years ago which is why I wasn't sure if it was animated or not.  For some reason I kept thinking it was MadTV, or at least live actors.  I may be co-mingling a few episodes in my head, but I also thought the person that ultimately "snapped" jumped out of a window to kill themselves, but again, I think the Simpsons episode was closest.  Thanks!!

I think they've used a variation on that premise numerous times over SNL's 40 year run. The one that jumps to my mind features newspaper reporters trying to decide on their lead story the day after the bombing of Pearl Harbor. Phil Hartman wants it to be the attack, but others think it should be the vandalism of some typewriters at the local high school and other mundane stories.
Watch the sketch here on NBC's SNL page.
